# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'column_name' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Spring-JPA wont save my entity because of this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'cryptocoin' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
```

But my MySQL column has more than enough VARCHAR LENGTH to actually handle the input.
For example the input was "CRYPTO ENTRY" and the LENGTH was

```
 `cryptocoin`  varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
```

So you cant tell me it's "too long".
Im using MySQL Workbench 8.0.16.

However when I remove the space between and insert it like this "CRYPTOENTRY" , Spring-JPA saves it.

Summary:

"CRYPTO ENTRY" (white space between) wont save.
"CRYPTOENTRY" (no white space between) will save.

Anyone have a fix for this bug?

Comment: Can you please share your table ddl and this entity field declaration?

Comment: Make sure you don't have trigger on your table.

Answer (score 1):

Error message clearly states that there is problem with column `column_name` and not `cryptocoin`

```
Data too long for column 'column_name' at row 1
```

Please check the length of `column_name` column and also validate the input for this column.

Comment: that was just an example, i updated the question. thank u!

Answer (score 0):

you may have created the column with small length
drop that column -> add column with new length -> the insert data